# Dynamically generate forms to edit an item in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an Item model, with a few attributes, which I show as a list on the home page.

I want to be able to make that `<li>`'s content into an edit form for that Item, and on submitting, if there were no validation errors, restore `<li>`'s contents (with updated values).

You can assume that the Item just has one string attribute named `title`, that should be enough for me to adapt into a bigger model.

How should I approach this? I'm guessing I need to somehow generate the forms on the server side, and bring them into the `li`, as it would be easy to integrate error handling with that, but I'm not sure how I can do that elegantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted an edit form with display:none, and made it appear on double click.

Answer (score 1):

I think "in place editing" is the term you are intrested in.
There are couple of gems available which can be helpfull with that. 
This one may satisfy your needs:[best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place)